# status 400 bad request when using another computer

Tags: http, postman, client, patch

I was testing my recently developed/released web application in another computer and in one of the http request it got a status 400. It works in all other computers in my company windows or linux, but for some reason it doesn`t work on my lenovo ideapad gaming3i with windows 10. I tested the application in firefox and chrome but I always get the same result.

So, I decided to make this same request on postman. I tested on 2 different PCs (making the exact same request)

```
PATCH http://cloud.tissuelabs.com/project

Header:
Cookie: x-access-token=***; project=8
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: ***
Host: cloud.tissuelabs.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 41

Body:
{
    "id": "8", 
    "name": "test"
}
```

In one of the PC it worked (status 200 OK). But in ideapad gaming3i, it didn't (status 400 bad request).

The response header:

```
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from localhost:3128
Via: 1.0 localhost:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Connection: close
```

The response body:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <TITLE>ERRO: A URL solicitada n&atilde;o pode ser recuperada</TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        <!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-serif}PRE{font-family:sans-serif}
        -->
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1>ERRO</H1>
    <H2>A URL solicitada n&atilde;o pode ser recuperada</H2>
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    <P>

        Na tentativa de recuperar a URL:
        <PRE>
PATCH /project HTTP/1.1
Cookie: x-access-token=eyJ***; project=8
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: f6***
Host: cloud.tissuelabs.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 41

{
    &quot;id&quot;: &quot;8&quot;, 
    &quot;name&quot;: &quot;test&quot;
}
</PRE>
        <P>
            O seguinte erro foi encontrado:
            <UL>
                <LI>
                    <STRONG>
Requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o inv&aacute;lida.
</STRONG>
            </UL>

            <P>
                Alguns aspectos de requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o HTTP s&atilde;o invalidos. Poss&iacute;veis causas:
                <UL>
                    <LI>M&eacute;todo desconhecido ou faltando (GET, POST)
                    <LI>Faltou a URL
                    <LI>Faltou o identificador HTTP (HTTP/1.0)
                    <LI>A requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o pode ser muito grande
                    <LI>Hostname com caracter inv&aacute;lido; n&atilde;o &eacute; permitido o uso de underscores
                </UL>
            </P>

            <BR clear="all">
            <HR noshade size="1px">
            <ADDRESS>
                Generated Tue, 08 Feb 2022 11:45:28 GMT by localhost (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
            </ADDRESS>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

I don't understand why the same request made from different computers results in different responses. Can anyone give me some light on this problem?

Comment: What is the response (apart from the response code)? Any payload? How about the access token in cookies? Perhaps you are not authenticated on this different laptop (it should ideally return 401, but perhaps the API simply returns 400 even in this situation).

Comment: @pavelsaman I added the access token to the cookie, but I won't share here, that is why I didn't wrote it in the question. I don't think it is authentication, because for get and post request I am getting a `status 200 ok`. besides, I pasted the exact same access token to make sure it wasn't authentication.

Comment: @pavelsaman I edited the question. There are no payloads besides the body of the request (JSON).